# Tweepy | Getting code 401 Invalid or expired token

Tags: python, tweepy

I am getting

```
"detail": "Token request failed with code 401, response was '{\"errors\":[{\"code\":89,\"message\":\"Invalid or expired token.\"}]}'."
```

Doing a request to the backend. Currently:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter_client = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
            api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
        )

    def get_token(self):
        # self.twitter_client = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
        #     api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
        # )
        return self.twitter_client.get_authorization_url()
```

When doing more than one request I am getting the error, but if I remove the comments in get_token(self), it works but I am not sure if there is a better or correct way for it. Do I have to do it for every other request that I have? Imagining that after this I need to get the User's token so will it have the same issue?